# Android Webview not resizing consistently when data is changed

Tags: android, webview

I am using the same Webview multiple times. When I load html that takes up more space, the webview expands to fit it, but once in awhile, it doesn't shrink back when less content is loaded into it again. How can I make this behavior more consistent?

Comment: Please, post your layout xml and related to WebView code from the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem, you can call new WebView(context) , then call webview.loadData(..), and add it to container layout every time when you have to reload a new data.

Don't define webview in xml(especially when scrollview is its parent), tried to add webview dynamically in code.